# sqlalchemy hybrid_property joining values from a relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a relatively simple model in which I want to join data from 2 tables as a hybrid_property. Something like the following, where `global_id` would be e.g. `fr-123` or `de-456`.

```
class Product(Base):
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'), nullable=False)
    country = relationship('Role', backref='product')

    @hybrid_property
    def global_id(self):
        return self.country.tld + "-" + self.product_id
```

This works fine for simple queries, but when I try to do searches using `LIKE` I get the error:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Product.country has an attribute 'tld'

I believe that I need to create an `expression` method that will handle this - but I'm not sure what form that expression needs to take!

Also would it make a difference if `country.tld` is also a `hybrid_property` ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgresql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings in the expression, in PostgreSQL you can do it with the operator `||`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tld = Column(String)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'), nullable=False)
    country = relationship('Country', backref='product')

    @hybrid_property
    def global_id(self):
        return self.country.tld + "-" + str(self.product_id)

    @global_id.expression
    def global_id(cls):
        return select([Country.tld.op('||')('-').op('||')(cls.product_id)]).\
               where(Country.id==cls.country_id).label('global_id')
```